# Memory management errors in the C language. Why are these errors?

Tags: c, memory-management, free

I am trying to find two errors related to memory allocation in this code snippet.    It was said in lecture that the first error was returning **class**, and the second was not freeing memory. I don't understand why the first is an error.  The second one I am not sure of, but have a good idea of why.

For the first error,  class is an array of students and the function getClassInfo returns a pointer to this array, seems fine to me.

I think I understand why memory should be free'd though.  On each iteration of the for loop thisStudent is allocated memory by malloc and then class[i] is assigned to the value of thisStudent.  On each iteration thisStudent is reassigned a new block of memory, but the last one is never free'd.

Any clarification as to why the first error is an error would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you
- Chris

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CLASS_SIZE 500

typedef struct student {
    int studentNr;
    char grade;
} student;

student * getClassInfo(void){
    int i;
    student class[CLASS_SIZE];

for(i = 0; i < CLASS_SIZE; i++){
    student * thisStudent = (student*) malloc(sizeof(student));
        if(thisStudent == NULL) return(NULL);
        scanf("%d %c", &(thisStudent->studentNr),&(thisStudent->grade));

        class[i] = *thisStudent;
        }
    return class;
}
```

I do get an warning saying its return the address of a local variable, when compiling, but how is that a error related to memory allocation?

Comment: Since the array is local to the function, it ceases to exist at function exit, so the pointer you are returning points to a now-deceased. This is probably the most asked question about C, I'm surprised you didn't find an answer already.

Comment: I agree I should have researched a bit more before asking,  sometimes I seem to figure out the problem better just by trying to ask a good question.   Thank you for your help though Matteo!

Comment: BTW, note that `class` is a keyword in C++, and would cause a compile error if you tried to compile this code with a C++ compiler.  It's not a problem as long as you're sticking strictly to C, but since *most* valid C code is also valid C++, and it's sometimes useful to be able to compile it as C++, it may be prudent to avoid using C++ keywords as identifiers in C programs.  Consider naming your array `students` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class` is a local variable within the `getClassInfo()` function, which means that it ceases to exist when that function returns.  The `return class;` statement returns a pointer that's no longer valid by the time the caller receives it.

You should declare `class` as a `student*` and allocate it dynamically with `malloc()`, just like you do for the students themselves.  That allocates it on the heap, so it continues to exist until you explicitly `free()` it.  You'll want to do `malloc(sizeof(student) * CLASS_SIZE)` to allocate contiguous space for all the student structures.

You're right that not freeing the `student` structures allocated in the loop is a bug (specifically, a memory leak).  You don't actually need to dynamically allocate students at all; you can just store the student number and grade into `class[i].studentNr` and `class[i].grade`.